# Using one Validator for multiple request DTOs? or multiple Validators for a single request DTO?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I have several ServiceStack request DTOs that implement an interface called IPageable. I have a validator that can validate the two properties that are on this interface. I think I'm going to end up having one validator per request type, but I'm trying to avoid having to duplicate that IPageable-related validation logic in all of them.

```cs
public class PageableValidator : AbstractValidator<IPageable>
{
    public PageableValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(req => req.Page)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
        RuleFor(req => req.PageSize)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1)
            .When(req => req.Page > 1);
    }
}
```

Some ideas I've had about this include:

1. It appears I can't just have container.RegisterValidators() apply
   this to all request types that implement IPageable, but that was my
   first thought.
2. can I specify multiple `<Validator>` attributes on all the request
   definitions, so that both a request-specific validator runs, as well
   as my IPageable validator?
3. can I specify at validator registration time that for all types
   implementing IPageable, my IPageable validator should run?
4. can I write a base class for my request-specific validators that
   gets the rules from my PageableValidator and includes / runs them?

I can make something sort of work by subclassing `AbstractValidator<T> where T : IPageable` , but I'd like to be able to do validation on more than one interface in more of an aspect-oriented way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answers to your questions but a few options came to mind to after reading your question.

I am not familiar with the `<Validator>` attribute, but in regards to question 2, you could create a [Filter attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) that would run your paging validation. This allows you to use many attributes on your request and set their priority.

```
public class PageableValidator : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    public void RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (requestDto is IPageable)
        {
            var validator = new PageableValidator(); //could use IOC for this
            validator.ValidateAndThrow(requestDto as IPageable);
        }

    }

    public IHasRequestFilter Copy()
    {
        return (IHasRequestFilter)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public int Priority { get { return -1; //setting to negative value to run it before any other filters} }
}
```

Another option would be creating an abstract class for Paging validation. This would require a subclass for every Request and requires a bit more code and some repetition*. Though, depending on how you want to handle your error messages you could move the code around.

```
public abstract class PagerValidatorBase<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public bool ValidatePage(IPageable instance, int page)
    {
        if (page >= 1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public bool ValidatePageSize(IPageable instance, int pageSize)
    {
        if (pageSize >= 1 && instance.Page > 1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}

public class SomeRequestValidator : PagerValidatorBase<SomeRequest>
{
    public SomeRequestValidator()
    {
        //validation rules for SomeRequest
        RuleFor(req => req.Page).Must(ValidatePage);
        RuleFor(req => req.PageSize).Must(ValidatePageSize);
    }
}
```

- IMO, the repetition makes the code more explicit (not a bad thing) and is okay since it isn't duplicating the logic.